# In a T-SQL check constraint, how to allow either a specific pattern or the empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, check-constraints

I have a phone-number pattern in place now.  I'd like to allow the empty string temporarily as a valid value.  What is the pattern for that? Here's the existing check:

```
( ([fax] like '[1-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
```

How would that pattern be changed to accept the empty string as well?

Comment: Simply, use `OR` operator [sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=216f42683edb9121f8e0f5bcee754c50)

Comment: Instead of empty string use `NULL` for missing values and your existing constraint will work.

Comment: @Martin Smith: That's reasonable, usually, but we're debugging something on the front end that involves a null value being rejected (not by SQL but by the CLR) so we're testing with String.Empty.

Comment: You're not using the [NANP Modern Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan#Modern_plan) rules? Whither are you calling?

Comment: @HABO:  If they enter a 1 as the first number, that's the least of our worries.This pattern is to prevent our lazy and unruly users from entering things like  "see notes" into the fax number field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would that pattern be changed to accept the empty string as well?

You could just use `or`:

```
(   
    [fax] = ''
    or [fax] like '[1-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
)
```